# How can I call a method from other Objective-C class?

Tags: objective-c, class, import

Let's say, in a.h file:

```
-(void)show;
```

in a.m file:

```
-(void)show{

//....

}
```

In b.m:

```
[self show];
```

How can I call `show` from b.m? I imported a.h by guess, but it has no effect.

Comment: What calls have you tried? Please include class names and how you created the object you are calling the method on.

Comment: May I politely suggest that you first start with a good tutorial on the basics of Objective-C. Your question is a really basic part of the Objective-C language. This site isn't really meant to teach people the basics. You'll make a lot more progress after working with some tutorials.

Comment: I'm included to agree with @rmaddy as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to call a method you need an instance of the object on which you call that method. For example, if your file `a.h` has a class `MyClassA`, then the call of `show` would look like this:

```
MyClassA *instanceA = [[MyClassA alloc] init];
[instanceA show];
```